# Unable to verify access token from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Our workflow is,

- We authenticate the user to get new access token by using the OAuth2 API
- Then we call the companies API with the new access token to get the list of companies that user is admin

But the second API call fails with 'Unable to verify access token' message. We tried to put some delay like 10s~30s between the calls, that sometimes succeed but not always. My guess is the newly created access token is not usable instantly for companies API.

Any idea what would be the amount of delay that can ensure that the newly received access token becomes available to other LinkedIn API services?

Or is there any way to overcome this failure so that the companies API call does not fail with the new access token?

Comment: anyone found fix?

Comment: After upgrading to a newer version of the LinkedIn API we did not see this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
I'm curious that the access token are mostly "Unable to verify access token" after granted by my code.
However, it always get succeed if I do the Oauth2 workflow manually by sending request on the browser one-by-one.